# Unable to find if radio button is checked

Tags: php, html

I have made a few radio buttons in my php code

```
echo "<input type='radio' name='rad' value='a'>";
echo "<input type='radio' name='rad' value='b'>";
```

and my html code is

```
<form method="post" action="fetch_page_4.php">
<input type="submit" name="submit1" value="Positive" id="btn1"/>
<input type="submit" name="submit2" value="Negative" id="btn2"/></form>
```

Whenever i click the Positive or Negative button it should go into the respective part in PHP...which it does. But the problem is that i need to find out which of my radio buttons is checked and take the action accordingly.
But i am unable to do so. My code for it is

```
if(isset($_POST['submit1']))
{
    $main_key=0;
    if(isset($_POST['rad']) && ($_POST['rad'])=='a')
    {
    $sub_arr=explode(" ",$array_subject[0]);
    $count_sub=count($sub_arr);
    $body_arr=explode(" ",$array_message[0]);
    $count_msg=count($body_arr);
    $main_key=1;
    }
}
```

If i echo the value of "main_key" after this...it is coming out to be 0, thus indicating that it is not going inside the loop even when the radio button is checked and has the required value.
Can somebody please tell me why is this happening?

Comment: It looks like you've handled if the radio button is set to "a," but what if you set it to "b"?  Perhaps that's what's happening?

Comment: The radio buttons have to be inside the form to be included in the data that is send back to the server.

Comment: @Helpful-I have written it for 'b' as well. Just didnt write it here